# Why are my React Testing Library tests so slow?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, create-react-app, aws-amplify, react-testing-library

My workplace has largish single page application, it was built in 2020 and uses Create React App for the build tool. Unfortunately, nearly every component takes an excessive amount of time to test. Sometimes it is longer than 300seconds, sometimes 100seconds, the fastest I've ever seen a test complete is 30seconds. Is this normal behaviour, if not, why are these tests taking such a long time?

[image]

While this code example is not reproducable, I am hoping that somebody may be able to take a read through it and highlight some possible problem areas:

```
// required imports from React & 3rd party libraries
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen, within } from '@testing-library/react';
import { API } from 'aws-amplify';

// react component to be tested, plus context and helper functions
import { MyComponent } from './MyComponent';
import { Store, UserContext, FurtherDetailContext } from 'store/store';
import * as helpers from 'helpers';

// mock data
import userContextMock from '../../../tests/fixtures/userContext/userContext.json';
import furtherDetailContextMock from '../../../tests/fixtures/furtherDetailContext/furtherDetailContext.json';
import gqlQueryResponse1 from '../../../tests/fixtures/gql/gqlQueryResponse1.json';
import gqlQueryResponse2 from '../../../tests/fixtures/gql/gqlQueryResponse2.json';
const mockJson = {
    this: 'is',
    an: 'example',
    response: true
};

const arrange = async () => {
    const mockToggleOpen = jest.fn();
    render(
        <Store>
            <UserContext.Provider
                value={{
                    userContext: userContextMock,
                    setUserContext: () => {
                        // do nothing
                    }
                }}>
                <FurtherDetailContext.Provider
                    value={{
                        furtherDetailContext: furtherDetailContextMock,
                        setFurtherDetailContext: () => {
                            /*do nothing */
                        }
                    }}>
                    <MyComponent myProps={mockJson} toggleOpen={mockToggleOpen} />
                </FurtherDetailContext.Provider>
            </UserContext.Provider>
        </Store>
    );

    // this component performs a network request before rendering
    await screen.findByText('text on the screen');
    const testid1 = screen.getByTestId('test-id-example');
    const testid2 = screen.getByTestId('test-id-example-2');
    return { testid1, testid2 };
};

describe('MyComponent', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        // get auth token
        jest.spyOn(helpers, 'getAuthtoken').mockResolvedValue('validAuthToken');
    });
    describe('all calls mocked', () => {
        beforeEach(() => {
            // mock graphql requests
            API.graphql = jest.fn().mockImplementation((url) => {
                const gqlQuery = url.query;
                if (RegExp('.*.mockGqlQuery*').test(gqlQuery)) {
                    return gqlQueryResponse1;
                }
                if (RegExp('.*.mockGql2*').test(gqlQuery)) {
                    return gqlQueryResponse2;
                }

                return;
            });
        });

        it('shows the original text on component mount', async () => {
            const { testid1 } = await arrange();
            expect(within(testid1).getByText('this text should be here')).toBeInTheDocument();
        });
    });
});
```

Here are the relevant dependencies:

```json
"dependencies": {
  "@types/node": "^12.12.50",
  "@types/react": "^17.0.52",
  "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.18",
  "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.7",
  "@types/react-leaflet": "^2.8.1",
  "aws-amplify": "^4.3.26",
  "leaflet": "^1.7.1",
  "react": "^17.0.1",
  "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
  "react-leaflet": ">=3.1.0 <3.2.0 || ^3.2.1",
  "@react-leaflet/core": ">=1.0.0 <1.1.0 || ^1.1.1",
  "react-router-dom": "^6.4.3",
  "typescript": "^3.7.5",
}
"devDependencies": {
  "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
  "@testing-library/dom": "^7.28.1",
  "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.6",
  "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.5",
  "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
  "@types/jest": "^26.0.4",
  "jest": "^26.6.3",
  "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
}
```

local development node version: v16.15.1

Comment: Is this just happening for you locally? How long do the tests take to complete when run in the CI/CD? Are you working as part of a team and does this happen to anyone else? 

This could be an issue with your machine, check your activity monitor (mac) or task manager (windows) to see if something is hammering your CPU, probably a node process.

EDIT: You are 2 major versions behind on RTL, so it may be worth seeing if you can safely upgrade

Comment: Thanks for the advice Jay, it's much appreciated. Yes, this happens with other members of the team, and is slow in the CI/CD pipeline too. I've been taking a look at the task manager and the CPU seems to be under control (just 3% utilised for Node). Also, good point about upgrading the RTL, I'll definitely give that a go!

Comment: Unfortunately, I found upgrading RTL too difficult for the ticket, as there was a peer dependency with React 18 (and going to React18 is a big job).

Comment: Can you please add some logs with the time that passes until they get called?
My immediate suspects would be `await screen.findByText('text on the screen');`, however the regex matching may also slow things down if the `url` is **very** long

Comment: You haven’t even provided code for the component under test or told us the node version.

Comment: Unfortunately the application is too large and convulated and I am unable to replicate it accurately. Please note in the question: "please let me know how speedy you've found the tests, and if you've found any ways to improve the speeds"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a well known issue that `create-react-app` is quite slow; and this issue is also extended to the tests.

The problem is probably `webpack`, your bundler program, sadly you can't easily decouple an app built with `create-react-app` from it.

My recommendation is to switch over to `vite`, and then to use vite's testing library: [vitest](https://vitest.dev) in particular.

(I believe you might keep your normal `create-react-scripts` and *only* use vitetest for testing.)

I understand that this is not the type of answer you might like to receive - it's not only *Yet Another Dependency* it also means changing a lot of the plumbing; but overall I found it incredibly useful to switch from `create-react-app` to `vite`; the speed difference is night and day.

Here's a [migration guide](https://vitest.dev/guide/migration.html) for vitest that you might find useful.

Comment: Thanks Joaquim. Thank you for taking the time to think about it. It's impossible to dianose the exact issue without seeing the full code (something I'm unable to do), and to provide general guidance and feedback is the exact answer I wanted. Cheers!

Comment: @mjwils, thank you kindly for the response. If you do switch to vitest would you tell me how that went? I've had great success in migrating from CRA to vite but I never kept CRA and executed only the tests through vitest. I'm going to assume that there's a lot of other projects that have the same problem.